# Crystal Reports equivalent of 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm familiar with SQL but not Crystal Reports.  I'm trying to deal with an imported data set with 5 columns:

```
id           deathDate           giftDate        giftAmount       Dead
123           2008-01-06          2011-09-08       25.00          TRUE
456           2009-06-08          2011-10-13       10.00          TRUE
789              0                2011-12-04       50.00          FALSE
...
```

I'm trying to do a subquery but can't figure out what the CR equivalent of WHERE in SQL would be.  I'd like to do something along the line of:

```
SELECT count(id) from tab1 where dead=TRUE
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the Select Expert (Report -> Select Expert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Conrad and dotjoe have observed, the Crystal equivalent of the sql `where` clause is the Select Expert - you should be able to find this on the Report menu.

If you need to include both true and false `Dead` records in the detail section, but want a total for only those records where `Dead` is true, the simplest way to do this would be to set up a formula item. To do so:

- Right-click on the Formula Fields option in the Field Explorer and select New... .
- Enter a suitable formula field name, like `DeadCount`.
- In the Formula editor, enter a formula like the following (assuming `Dead` is a string):

  `If {tab1.Dead} = 'TRUE' then 1`
- Use the `x-2` button (or Alt-C) to check that the formula does not have any errors, then press the Save and Close button to exit the formula editor.
- Drag and drop the new formula field from the Field Explorer onto anywhere in the report.
- Right-click on the formula field that you have just added to the report and select Insert > Summary... from the menu.
- In the Insert Summary dialog, specify the Summary operation as Sum and the Summary location as Grand Total (Report Footer), then click OK. A summarised field, labelled something like `Sum of @DeadCount`, should appear in the Report Footer. (You should now remove the un-summarised formula field from where you placed it in the report design area.)

This technique is essentially similar to including a summed case value in a sql query - something like: `select sum(case when Dead = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as DeadCount from tab1`

Comment: +1 You describe an alternate way to implement their "Running Total" field.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the record selection formula...

```
{datasetname.Dead} = true 
//note: I'm not sure what data type that is but CR uses bool for bit and XSD bool
```

Then add a summary field to the report footer which does the count(id).

Or, if you need to display the dataset and only need a subquery you can use something called a "Running Total" field. In here you can do the count(id) and add the where clause to the necessary formula.