# Equivalent of WHERE clause in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, where-clause

This Crystal Report program was dumped on my lap and I'm brand new to it. I understand the concept, but I'm hitting a wall here.

There is another question that's similar:
[Crystal Reports equivalent of 'WHERE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439169/crystal-reports-equivalent-of-where)

But it and the answers are directed towards (it seems) "totaling" the column, whereas I want to simply *only show* the row if one of the columns (in this case, if "CostType" is equal to 0).

I have two data tables I'm reading from to create this report. They're joined via a common column name (ItemKey). Unfortunately, in the second table, there are multiple records of the same item. I only want the item(s) with a CostType of 0.

This is stupidly easy in SQL, even for a beginner like me, but I can't figure out how to effectively say: "only show an item if the CostType is 0" with Crystal Reports.

Item_Cost Table (example):

```
ItemKey      Special         Cost         CostType
001          TRUE            55.00        0
002          FALSE           10.00        0
003          TRUE            20.00        1
```

Item Table (example):

```
ItemKey      Description     Mode  
001          Whatever        EE 
002          Random          AB 
003          Unimportant     GE
```

---

What shows up:

```
Item         Description     Mode  
Box          Whatever        EE 
Square       Random          AB 
Circle       Unimportant     GE
```

What I want to show:

```
Item         Description     Mode  
Box          Whatever        EE 
Square       Random          AB
```

---

I hope this all makes sense. Basically, if this was a SQL query, I'd just say "WHERE CostType = 0" at the end and I wouldn't get all of the other items that have different cost types.

I should mention that this is entirely handled by Crystal Reports. I'm not using a SQL string and passing it in or something. The function for showing the window is as follows:

```
    Dim PartsDemandReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = New crptIndentedBomXLBom
    PartsDemandReport.SetDataSource(GLOBAL_VARIABLES.GlobalBomIndented)

    Dim CrystalReportViewerForm As New frmCrystalReportViewer
    CrystalReportViewerForm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = PartsDemandReport
    CrystalReportViewerForm.Show()
    PartsDemandReport = Nothing
```

If there's a way to simply force Crystal Reports to add that "WHERE CostType = 0", that'd be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There are couple of ways to do this:**

1. If you don't need the `CostType not equal to 0` in whole report then you can directly give in `select expert` which acts as `where clause` for crystal reports.

**Example:**

go to `Report ---> Selection Formula ---> Record` this open formula window in that add below line

```
CostType = 0
```

This will ensure only cost type = 0 will be retrived from database

2.If you require `cost type <> 0`  any where in report. Then add below condition for `Item`, `Description` and `Mode` Columns

**Example**

```
@Item:

if cost type = 0 
then <<Database Item field >>
```

Place it in detail part of Item column.

In the same way do for other columns as well.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. Today is a day off, but as soon as I can get back into the office, I will try this.

Comment: Np @Keith... if you face any issue let me know.

Comment: I finally got back at the office after a long weekend. I tried your solution, but with one tweak: putting "CostType = 0" under 'Group Selection' as 'Record Selection' wouldn't work.

You have no idea how much time you've saved me. Thank you very much! I'd up-vote if I had the 15 required to do so. :)

Comment: @Keith... No problem... I am glad that problem was solved... Happy to help always... don't place under `Group` but place your conditon on another option available that is `Record`

Comment: Any idea why Group would be doing what is desired and not Record?

Comment: Okay. I will keep fiddling with it and keep an eye out. Thanks again, Siva