# Equivalent of "WHERE" SQL in crystal report Record Selection

Tags: crystal-reports

So I've worked with crystal Report a bit before but I'm getting stuck on this particular problem.
The question is very similar to this one [Equivalent of WHERE clause in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142700/equivalent-of-where-clause-in-crystal-reports?noredirect=1&lq=1) , however in that question the value of the parameter was static and not a selectable parameter.

My company uses a report that allows the user to select one or multiple machine numbers and gets the data for each one of them. Due to a change in our organization these machines are now being grouped for the departments they're in so the user shall only be able to select the department number and in return get the data for all the machines in that department.

my idea was to create a sort of translation table where all the previous machine numbers get paired with their new department numbers.
I could easily do the selection in SQL with `SELECT translationtable.machine_number WHERE translationtable.dep_number = INPUT`
however I have no idea how to do this in crytal reports syntax.

Comment: Add `translationtable` to Crystal data model, link it to existing data by `machine_number` and match its `dep_number` with user selection in record selection formula.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports, go to ***Report, Selection Formulas, Record...***

That dialog allows you to enter a record selection expression.

Comment: yes I know this is where I've tried to modify our old report already. In the old version every machine number input only had one entry that got selected. However now I need to select multiple machine numbers based on the single department number input,